# What are the measurements on this slope angle tool?

Tags: navigation, avalanche, orienteering

I totally need [one of these](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Shavenraspberry-Navigators-Slope-Angle-Tool/dp/B00K9733G2)

[image]

This helps you estimate the slope angle on a contour map by measureing the gaps between the contour lines. This is to help you avoid avoid avalanche areas.

I'm sure I could work this out but my maths is terrible. Anyone know what the mm gap is between each of the markers on this tool?

Comment: Could you be a bit more precise about "what the mm gap is between each of the markers on this tool"? I'm sure I could figure out the math, however, I don't understand from your question, what I'm supposed to figure out ;-)

Comment: Which particular markers are you referring to?

Comment: Keep in mind when you're measuring slope that the slope isn't always a "slope." I charted a slope for a summit attempt not long ago, but when we got to the mountain we discovered that our projected "slope" from the topographic map was actually a series of very steep steps 20-30m in height.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[image: Image capture from John Balwin's website]

<sup>Source: [John Baldwin: Slope Angles from Map Contours](http://www.johnbaldwin.ca/trip-planning-slope.asp)</sup>

View [this page](http://geokov.com/education/slope-gradient-topographic.aspx) for a refresher on how to do the maths to calculate slope on a topographic map.